# How to let Code Analysis pick up that an argument was validated in called method

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Normally if I would have had this:

```
public string Foo(string text)
{
    return text.Substring(3);
}
```

I would have gotten a `CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods` from code analysis. It would have been fixed by modifying the code as such:

```
public string Foo(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    else if (string.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace(text)
        throw new ArgumentException("May not be empty or white space", "text")
    else if (text.Length < 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be at least 3 characters long", "text");
    return text.Substring(3);
}
```

But now I want to use another means of doing this validation:

```
public string Foo(string text)
{
    Validator.WithArgument(text, "text").NotNullEmptyOrWhitespace().OfMinLength(3);
    return text.Substring(3);
}
```

since the method validates the argument the code analysis rule is satisfied but you still get a `CA1062` warning. Is there a way to suppress the Code Analysis rule for cases like these without manually suppressing them each time or turning off that specific Code Analysis rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute named [`ValidatedNotNullAttribute`](http://esmithy.net/2011/03/15/suppressing-ca1062/) can be used for indicating that a parameter is validated in a helper method.  However, it's not necessarily a great choice for a fluent validation API since [you would need to add it to a parameter of the wrong method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244958/suppress-ca1062-with-fluent-validation#8245334) (your `WithArgument` method, as opposed to your `NotNullEmptyOrWhitespace` method).